# split string by using regex in python

Tags: python, regex, split

What is the best way to split a string like

```
text = "hello there how are you"
```

in Python?

So I'd end up with an array like such:

```
['hello there', 'there how', 'how are', 'are you']
```

I have tried this:

```
liste = re.findall('((\S+\W*){'+str(2)+'})', text)
for a in liste:
    print(a[0])
```

But I'm getting:

```
hello there 
how are 
you
```

How can I make the `findall` function move only one token when searching?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution with `re.findall`:

```py
>>> import re
>>> text = "hello there how are you"
>>> re.findall(r"(?=(?:(?:^|\W)(\S+\W\S+)(?:$|\W)))", text)
['hello there', 'there how', 'how are', 'are you']
```

Have a look at the Python docs for `re`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

- `(?=...)` Lookahead assertion
- `(?:...)` Non-capturing regular parentheses

Answer (score 1):

If regex isn't require you could do something like:

```py
l = text.split(' ')
out = []
for i in range(len(l)):
    try:
        o.append(l[i] + ' ' + l[i+1])
    except IndexError:
        continue
```

Explanation:

First split the string on the space character. The result will be a list where each element is a word in the sentence. Instantiate an empty list to hold the result. Loop over the list of words adding the two word combinations seperated by a space to the output list. This will throw an IndexError when accessing the last word in the list, just catch it and continue since you don't seem to want that lone word in your result anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you actually need regex for this.
I understand you want a list, in which each element contains two words, the latter also being the former of the following element. We can do this easily like this:

```py
string = "Hello there how are you"
liste = string.split(" ").pop(-1)
# we remove the last index, as otherwise we'll crash, or have an element with only one word
for i in range(len(liste)-1):
    liste[i] = liste[i] + " " + liste[i+1]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's mandatory for you need to use regex, but I'd do this way.

First, you can get the list of words with the `str.split()` method.

```py
>>> sentence = "hello there how are you"
>>> splited_sentence = sentence.split(" ")
>>> splited_sentence
['hello', 'there', 'how', 'are', 'you']
```

Then, you can make pairs.

```py
>>> output = []
>>> for i in range (1, len(splited_sentence) ):
...     output += [ splited[ i-1 ] + ' ' + splited_sentence[ i ] ]
...
output
['hello there', 'there how', 'how are', 'are you']
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is just to `split`, `zip`, then `join` like so...

```
sentence = "Hello there how are you"
words = sentence.split()
[' '.join(i) for i in zip(words, words[1:])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution using `findall`.

```
>>> liste = list(map(''.join, re.findall(r'(\S+(?=(\s+\S+)))', text)))
>>> liste
['hello there', 'there how', 'how are', 'are you']
```